# Use data from R cell in Python cell of databricks notebook

Tags: databricks

Is this possible and if so how? As a simple example I might have an R cell like the following

```
%r
x <- rbinom(10, 100, .5)
```

How can I access `x` from a Python cell?

Answer (score 1):

A small excerpt from the Databricks website - [mix-languages](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#mix-languages)

> When you invoke a language magic command, the command is dispatched to
> the REPL in the execution context for the notebook. **Variables defined
> in one language (and hence in the REPL for that language) are not
> available in the REPL of another language.** REPLs can share state only
> through external resources such as files in DBFS or objects in object
> storage.

Some workarounds that I have seen on stackoverflow

1. Save in file in DBFS and read it back in python cell.
2. Other not tested/not recommended options.

   2.1. Set environmental variable in one language and then read the same in another language.
   2.2. Set value as a spark - conf and then read back in another language cell.

The file option works well. The other options I have not been able to pass along reliably. Maybe it is just for me.

Please validate and see if it works for you...